# Xamarin forms map coordinates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two question about xamarin forms map.
1. How can I get coordinates of map center (long, lat) after map drag?
2. Is it possible to get coordinates from tap event on map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need custom map renderers.

This is how to get tapped coordinates on map for Android:

```
public class CustomImportantPlaceRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    GoogleMap map;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        if (map != null)
        {
            map.MapClick -= googleMap_MapClick;
        }

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;

        if (map != null)
        {
            map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
            map.MapClick += googleMap_MapClick;
            map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void googleMap_MapClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs e)
    {
        double latitude = e.Point.Latitude;
        double longitude = e.Point.Longitude;

        MessagingCenter.Send<String, ClickedPositionCO>("PositionClicked", "PositionClickedDetail", new ClickedPositionCO(latitude, longitude));
    }
}
```

And this is how to get tapped coordinates on map for iOS

```
public class CustomImportantPlaceRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    private readonly UITapGestureRecognizer tapRecognizer;

    public CustomImportantPlaceRenderer()
    {
        tapRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer(OnTap)
        {
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            NumberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        };
    }

    private void OnTap(UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        var cgPoint = recognizer.LocationInView(Control);

        var location = ((MKMapView)Control).ConvertPoint(cgPoint, Control);

        MessagingCenter.Send<String, ClickedPositionCO>("PositionClicked", "PositionClickedDetail", new ClickedPositionCO(location.Latitude, location.Longitude));
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer);
        }

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
            nativeMap.ShowsUserLocation = true;
            Control.AddGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it if map is create in PCL by "new Map()"? Can you write some code how to use it by dependencyService. Thank you.